# Copy location/rotation information in Unity

Tags: unity, transformation

I place a cube in my level (scaled along one axis) and start doing something else.

Then I place another cube, but want to copy and paste the location and rotation data from the first cube onto this new one.

So far I'm doing that by copying & pasting 6 numbers one by one. Is there a faster way to clone the location/rotation of an object (eg. with a single key press)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In editor: Select your first game object by clicking on it. Then right click the transform of the first object and click "Copy Component". Then select the other game object, right click its transform and click "Paste Component Values".

Edit: I made you a gif!

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is there a key button for copy and paste component?

Comment: I don't think so. The thing is you can't really select a component (as far as I know) so I don't think there's a way to know which component you're on for a single button press to know what to copy. Although I may be wrong about this